# how to receive notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging through APNS in an Objective C Framework?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am building a cocoa touch framework (using objective C) to be implemented in other apps, this framework is intended to receive and display Notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging through APNS. I’ve done some research, and I have identify the next process in order to get notifications from APNS:

1. APNs Authentication Key or certificate for application should set on
   FCM server.
2. The device should ask for APNS token (device token) using
   `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` from
   UIKit framework.
3. Then APNs or device token must be sent to FCM.
4. In retrieve it will return FCM token or registration token using
   FIRMessagingDelegate didReceiveRegistrationToken (method that will
   be call when token is generated).
5. After that, this FCM token should be sent to the server (in case
   notifications are being sent to individual devices).
6. So, when a server sends notification to devices, will go through
   APNS and they will be received using
   `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification`

I have some question about this process.

1. How can I get APNS Token in my framework ? , or is it supposed to be
   done in the application itself ?
2. FCM token (using APNS and not a direct channel) will be receive once
   I sent APNS or device token to FCM. But I have observed that
   developers do this on their applications, how can I so this in my
   framework ?

I can not find a good aproach to manage all this inside my framework.